# Is it possible to trigger onEdit function on formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a complicated formula in column P that checks about 6 conditions and returns 1 or 0. I want to hide every row with 1 in column P. I use this script:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = sheet.getActiveRange();
  if (r.getColumnIndex() == 16 && r.getValue() == "1")
    sheet.hideRows(r.getRowIndex(),1);
}
```

For reasons unknown, the script doesn't work. It seems that onEdit can't be triggered on formula... Is it really so? How can I make the script work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work because the cell with the formula itself isn't being edited. It's not the active range, so `r.getValue() != 1`, it equals whatever you just typed in, and `r.getColumnIndex()` should never be 16.

set:

```
var r=sheet.getActiveRange();
var row=r.getRowIndex();
var p=sheet.getRange("P"+row);
```

And

```
if(p.getValue()==1)
    sheet.hideRows(row,1);
```

That should work, assuming your conditions are on the same row as your `p` that you want to test against.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Your solution is quite close to what I need. I have a subquestion, though: is it possible to hide target row and 2 rows above it? I've tried                                     `if(p.getValue()==1)
  sheet.hideRows(row,-2);`                                          but with no luck.

Comment: try: `if(p.getValue()==1) sheet.hideRows(row-2,3)`

Answer (score 1):

In May 2013, a "Change" trigger was added for spreadsheets, and it delivers an event for formula changes.

Comment: "onChange" doesn't fire on formula result change: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41591675