# onEdit script not firing on Google Sheet in formula based cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm completely new to Google script writing, but I've used various posts to piece together what I need: Something that adds grey borders to each cell in every sheet within my Google Sheets when its not empty and white borders when cells are empty.

```
function onEdit(range) {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  range.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "white", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
    var values = range.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
            if (values[i][j] !== "") {
                range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "#dfdfdf", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly when I manually change the data in any cell; however, on those cells where the script is monitoring, pulls data from another sheet fails to fire the trigger/script. How can I get around this so that cells with formulas (that reference other sheets) will still fire my script?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That's normal behavior.  Simple triggers only respond to user actions. You can read about it [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/).  Also the only parameter you can pass in a trigger is the event object.    Your function is working because you redefined the range to be a datarange.

Comment: Suppose if I define a custom range say A1:C100 and want to apply this kind of trigger when ever the value changes according to the formulas then what can be done in this case?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you changing information on another sheet that is being used in formulas in the sheet where you want the borders to change?

Comment: Exactly. Now you got me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on information in the comments.

In `var range` change `.getActiveSheet()` to `.getSheetByName('Sheet1')` where sheet1 is the sheet where you want the borders to be set.

Currently, when you edit your sheet `.getActiveSheet()` is getting the sheet where you're making the edit, instead what you want is when you edit any sheet in the spreadsheet you want this script to only work on a specific sheet hence `.getSheetByName('Sheet1')`

**EDIT**

The triggers don't fire if the edit or change is made by a formula. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41586926/onchange-trigger-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: The thing is sometimes the values are changing without editing any sheet. Say e.g values in the sheet1 A1 is being updated based on the value of sheet2 A1 and that has a formula of a date. Now if date changes in sheet2 A1, value in sheet1 A1 is updated where I am trying to apply the borders based on values wherever defined in the criteria. So here, none of the sheets are being edited but are being updated automatically and I want to fire my trigger should fire on this value update in sheet1.

Comment: Correction, the triggers don't fire if the update if caused by a formula.

Comment: Then I am still there where I was. I want to fire my trigger on a change made by a formula.

Comment: Yes, back to square 1. There are some workarounds online but they don't seem to be very reliable!  Could a time-based trigger work along with an onEdit trigger so that at least the trigger will fire at set intervals and in the event of an edit?

Comment: I have tried time-based triggers too but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Hey Athar, have you got the solution?