# How to run a filter based on formula result in column?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets-formula, rowfilter

I have the following which works great when I type the word "HIDE".  But when the "HIDE" is the result of a formula, it is not recognized.  What would you suggest?  My goal is to have the rows automatically hidden when the trigger column returns the formula result.
Here is what I have:

```
function onEdit(f) {
  if (f.range.getColumn() == 30 && f.value == "HIDE") {
    f.range.getSheet().hideRows(f.range.getRow());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check for range's [`getDisplayValue`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValue()):

```
if (f.range.getColumn() == 30 && f.range.getDisplayValue() == "HIDE")
```

It always gives you value of cell content "as displayed".

Comment: Thank you.  I also read somewhere that onEdit does not respond to formula result changes, only user changes.  Of course, the formula fires when the user makes a change in a separate column.

Comment: You can set `onChange` trigger for that case, it will fire when formula result is updated.

Comment: I now have the following, and have set up an onChange trigger.  Still no results.   function FilterRows(f) {
  if (f.range.getColumn() == 30 && f.range.getDisplayValue() == "HIDE") {
    f.range.getSheet().hideRows(f.range.getRow());
  }
}

Comment: Yes, I was wrong about it, onChange doesn't fire when formula result is updated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41591675

Comment: Is your formula value being updated after you update values in some cells? Then you can add onEdit trigger, and instead check not for edited range, but for whole 30th column range and hide needed rows.

Comment: The 24th column has dates, and the 30th has an array formula that returns "HIDE" if corresponding date in the same row is "<today()-60".  In other words, 30th column is set to hide if the date is older than 2 months.  I would be happy to evaluate the 24th column directly, perhaps on a time trigger.  I just don't know how; I'm new to this.  I used to do a little VBA, but it's been awhile.

Comment: Ok, then you can get rid of 30th column and add time-driven trigger that will run once each day and check for values in 24th column: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually